# SRVE0295E error on integrating Bluemix application with SSO service using cloud directory

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am facing an issue with SSO integration (cloud directory) with a Liberty for Java application.

I have Liberty application which is integrated with SSO service using Cloud directory. I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_service.html#tsk_creatingsso)

When I access the homepage of the application, I am getting `"Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500 "` error message. Logs aren't providing any useful information.

The steps that I followed are listed below

1. Created a simple Liberty for Java webapp, named SSODemo and deployed on Bluemix. I could access home page of the application
2. Created SSO service. Created Cloud directory and added a couple of users and saved
3. Added the following in web.xml file of SSODemo

SSODemoSecurity
    
        Secured
        /
        /
        */
        /SSODemo/*
        GET
        PUT
        HEAD
        TRACE
        POST
        DELETE
        OPTIONS
    
    
        TESTROLE

4. Copied ssodemo.war file to folder `c:\deploy2bluemix\apps`
5. Created server.xml file in `c:\deploy2bluemix`. Added role. server.xml would look as below

   ```
   <featureManager> 
       <feature>jsp-2.2</feature> 
       <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
   </featureManager> 

   <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/> 


   <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/> 

   <application type="war" id="SSODemo" name="SSODemo" location="SSODemo.war" context-root="/"> 
       <application-bnd> 
           <security-role name="TESTROLE"> 
               <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/> 
           </security-role> 
       </application-bnd> 
   </application>
   ```
6. Pushed SSODemo app from  c:\deploy2bluemix
7. Bound the SSO service created with SSODemo app
8. restaged SSODemo app
9. Saved the default details populated on Integrate tab of SSO Service
10. Now, when I launch SSODemo app, it asks for user id and password. On providing valid user id and password it throws "Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500 " error message
11. Following is the log entry when the above error message is thrown

    bmssodemo-mc.mybluemix.net - [10/02/2016:03:36:26 +0000] "GET /oidcclient/redirect/GIC5KC6sbK?scope=openid&code=lS9jAkiKSPmC8VNJw0NFULgqMkXEpP&state=f0hvnV7R4iSsUDwU5hzr HTTP/1.1" 500 0 42 "https://ssoq3-gikup9q8qk-cp16.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/authsvc?PolicyId=urn:ibm:security:authentication:asf:basicldapuser" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 192.155.237.118:32103 x_forwarded_for:"125.16.236.150" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:4844e729-a9d6-4efb-579a-a5c6449db8ff response_time:0.227078783 app_id:7b8c1d84-2cb0-420a-8735-198ee50dcf62 x_global_transaction_id:"40112183"

Any guidance here to resolve the issue will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the Bluemix status page is reporting a notification opened on Feb 5th about an issue of SSO service with the liberty runtime.

Check on
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Answer (score 0):

Liberty for Java runtime provided an urgent update for this issue today. I don't think you need the workaround now. Please give it a try.